# Memory leak or it is normal behavior?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a app with threads, pop up windows, timers, etc. So when i start app it start from `24 mb`.

[image: chart]

When i do a lot of operations, memory increasing, but never will go back... Is this normal behavior ?

If not, how do i can find reason, because i use `NSOperationQueue` for all my threads.

```
struct GVariables {
    static let globalBackgroundQueue = { () -> NSOperationQueue in
            let oq = NSOperationQueue()
            oq.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
            return oq
        }()
}
```

then use:

```
GVariables.globalBackgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Every time you call let oq = NSOperationQueue() a new instance is instantiated. Why not just let globalBackgroundQueue = NSOperationQue() then set the maxConcurrentOperationCount in init or viewDidLoad?

Comment: i created: ```struct GVariables {}```  and put this function in it... Is this bad?

Comment: That's fine.  It's static so it will only get created once

Comment: This could be different things, using memory doesn't always mean you have a memory leak. Are you getting memory warnings or app terminations due to memory? If you are, that doesn't mean you have a memory leak either, it just means you'er using too much memory. If you have objects that are strong ref. cycled and can never be deallocated then you could have a memory leak (but no warnings and still low RAM usage). It's two dif. things.

Comment: yes, i didn't receive any warnings... but is it normal that in never go back to 24 mb., and only increase with each button click for example... But operation finish successfully after i click button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly doesn't seem like normal behavior.  It appears that your application has a memory leak.  My recommendation is that you use Instruments to find out if anything is leaking, and if so, what.

Apple has an [Instruments Users Guide for Finding Leaked Memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html)